# Ruby on Rails Image display

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, image, web-applications

So I am trying to make a website where you can upload your images and view them. I am done with the upload part and partially with the show part but I can't get them to display together. I get unwanted spaces between the images. For example right now I am getting a row with 4 images and then the next row has 1 image only(I could not upload a screenshot because i dont have enough reputation points, Sorry). I have tried everything i know to fill the free space but did not succeed.My show view code is,

```
<%= render 'nav' %>
<div id = "jags_show">
<h1>Your Jags </h1>
<div id = "clear"></div>
<hr />
<% if @jags.empty? %>
<p> NO JAGS UPLOADED YET <p>
<% else %>
<% @jags.each do |j| %>
    <div id = "jags">
        <p id = "jagimage"><%= image_tag j.image_url(:thumb) %></p>
        <p id = "jagname"> <%= j.name %> </p>
        <div class="actions">
         <%= link_to "update", edit_jag_path(j) %> |
         <%= link_to "remove", j, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
        </div>
    </div>
 <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

My CSS is

```
#jags{
display: inline;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #222;
border: 2px solid white;
}
#jagname{
position: relative;
margin-left: 10px;
font-family: Helvetica; 
color:#c1f706;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
}
#jagimage img{
border: 1.5px solid white;
}
#jags_show{
background-image:url('background.jpg');
margin-left: 80px;
margin-right: 40px;
margin-top: 80px;

}
#jags_show h1{
padding-top: 80px;
color: #434341;
font-family: Pilgi;
font-size: 35px;
background-color: #f0f0f0;
display:inline;
position: absolute;
margin-top:-100px;
}
#clear{
clear:both; 
}
.actions a{
color: #b3b2b1;
text-decoration: none;

}
.actions {
text-align: center;
padding: 0px;

}
```

Any suggestion/advice would be appreciated. Thank you.
Oh and I am using the CarrierWave Gem if that is of any help.

So i got my code to run on jsfiddle and it looks fine there, which makes me think that the problem I am having is due to the different orientation of the images.
Here is my jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/cVvYE/embedded/result/

Comment: If you place your problen into jsfiddle.net and post it here, iam sure you find a quick answer

Comment: Thankyou for the tip, I'll do it right away

Answer (score 0):

The spaces are due to `display: inline;`, any space in the HTML (or new line) will be displayed as, well, a space. Try changing to `display: block` and floating where necessary, this will remove the spacing. Also, your images will need to have `display: block;` too, as they are `inline` by default.